# How to update Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, installation

I recently installed Microsoft Visual Studio community verion 2015 on my computer for educational purposes. However while installation I conservatively chose not to install the source files for C/C++. Is there any way to rectify this? There doesn't seem to be any update menu in Visual Studio where I can do this.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U1MRUiJAOq0

Comment: Or a shiny new install of the 2017 RC .

Comment: Just run the installation again. It will give you an option to add or remove components.

Comment: open control panel->programs&features, select the visual studio 2015 with updates entry adn select change/modify and here select the VC++ files you miss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install any of the custom components (Visual C++, Visual F#, others) later if you don’t select them during the initial setup, there have some methods to modify VS to select the custom components to update and you can have a look at the following:

1. Go to Control Panel—Programs and Features, right click the Visual Studio Community 2015 with updates and Change, it popups the VS installer windows and click **Modify** button, then you can find the option ‘Visual C++’ under Programming Languages and check it, click ‘Next’ button to install it like the following screenshot.
2. If you still store the installer file of the Visual Studio Community 2015 with update 3 on your computer, right click it and run it as administrator, click **Modify** button and you can find the same installer windows as the above, check the option ‘Visual C++’ to install it.
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

You can have Visual Studio check for any updates itself by going to *Tools > Extensions & Updates > Updates > Product Updates*.